# Getting perceptualdiff output image similar to ImageMagick’s output

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, diff

Is there a way I can get the output of perceptualdiff similar to the one of ImageMagick, rather than a dark xray-like image as shown below?

perceptualdiff output

[image]

ImageMagick output

[image]

Comment: Huh? Where are the files you compared and how did you compare them?

Comment: Please post the original images which you used as input for your diffs.

Comment: the images attached to thread are more of an output examples of the way ImageMagick & perceptualdiff showed up. Just that i wanted a more good readable output like Imagemagick!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

It seems that I mis-read the OP's question at first. He wants to get an output like ImageMagick's `compare` produces, though from a different tool, `perceptualdiff`. I mistook it and answered as if he wanted a `perceptualdiff`-like output from ImageMagick!

Before this question, I was not aware of **[perceptualdiff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/)** at all.

After [downloading it](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=166838) and playing very shortly with it, I cannot see that there are ***any*** options to tweak its output "delta" image to look anything like ImageMagick's `compare -compose src-over`!

The perceptualdiff-website links to some papers which supposedly describe the algorithm it uses, and the advantages of it. I didn't have time to read it...

I'll leave my original answer stand below as it is, for the benefit of future readers.

---

Since the quality thoughts of the OP did not care to provide any input images to play with, let's create our own... The result is below:

[image]  [image]

Is there a difference between them? Let's see...

### 1. 'Standard' `compare` command provided by ImageMagick

If you call `compare` with no options at all, ImageMagick will implicitly apply a `-compose src-over` setting for the composition:

```
compare                             \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyrE.png \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQjz.png \
 delta1.png
```

The result of this comparison, `delta1.png` is the image on the left, below. Take note of the following facts:

1. `delta1.png` has put the "original" image (i.e. the first one mentioned on the command line) as a somewhat paled background image to the composition delta image.
2. In the foreground are the red pixels where the second image do not match the original images.

### 2. Calling `compare` with a custom `-highlight-color`

It seems that the border pixels are also different. However, our eyes may be fooled by the fact that the input images already have a red border. So let's run a slightly modified command:

```
compare                             \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyrE.png \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQjz.png \
-highlight-color green              \
 delta3.png
```

The resulting image is below, on the right. As you can see, the "diff" pixels are green now. Both "delta" PNGs so far suggest two main differences:

1. that the 'Hello' world is slightly displaced horizontally when comparing the two input images
2. that the red frame around each image is slightly different in color.

[image]  [image]

### 3. Calling `compare` with a custom `-lowlight-color`

To get closer to the desired output of the OP, we can add `-lowlight-color black` and change the highlight color to white:

```
compare                             \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyrE.png \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQjz.png \
-highlight-color white              \
-lowlight-color black               \
 delta2.png
```

The result is below, on the left. Looks already similar to what the OP wants, no?

### 4. Using `compare` with `-compose MinusSrc`

Another, similar output is produced by modifying the implicit composition mode and replace it by `-compose minussrc`:

```
compare                             \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyrE.png \
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQjz.png \
-compose minussrc                   \
 delta-minussrc.png
```

The result is below, on the right.

[image]  [image]

### 5. Testing out `compare` with all composition modes it supports

There are more than 5 dozen composition modes built into ImageMagick. The following command lists them all:

```
convert -list compose
```

You will see the following list:

> Atop
>   Blend
>   Blur
>   Bumpmap
>   ChangeMask
>   Clear
>   ColorBurn
>   ColorDodge
>   Colorize
>   CopyBlack
>   CopyBlue
>   CopyCyan
>   CopyGreen
>   Copy
>   CopyMagenta
>   CopyOpacity
>   CopyRed
>   CopyYellow
>   Darken
>   DarkenIntensity
>   DivideDst
>   DivideSrc
>   Dst
>   Difference
>   Displace
>   Dissolve
>   Distort
>   DstAtop
>   DstIn
>   DstOut
>   DstOver
>   Exclusion
>   HardLight
>   HardMix
>   Hue
>   In
>   Lighten
>   LightenIntensity
>   LinearBurn
>   LinearDodge
>   LinearLight
>   Luminize
>   Mathematics
>   MinusDst
>   MinusSrc
>   Modulate
>   ModulusAdd
>   ModulusSubtract
>   Multiply
>   None
>   Out
>   Overlay
>   Over
>   PegtopLight
>   PinLight
>   Plus
>   Replace
>   Saturate
>   Screen
>   SoftLight
>   Src
>   SrcAtop
>   SrcIn
>   SrcOut
>   SrcOver
>   VividLight
>   Xor

If you are curious, you can test them out easily. The following command creates a delta PNG for each one:

```
 convert -list compose                          \
  | while read compositionmode ; do
          compare                               \
             https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLyrE.png \
             https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHQjz.png \
           -compose ${compositionmode}          \
            delta-${compositionmode}.png
  done
```

---

*(Note, the input files provided above are not necessarily the best ones to demonstrate the features and advantages of the respective composition mode.)*

Comment: Excellent explanation on ImageMagick compare.                       I suppose perceptualdiff might not have the same image output as ImageMagick.        One downside i felt about using ImageMagick was that i didnt get a standalone linux package to run it without installing as i was using it on JENKINS(Continous integration tool) for automating of compare webapages..

Comment: @QualityThoughts: *"Excellent..."* -- but no upvote?!?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle - Well, for the effort Im giving a upVote!!, but i wasn't expecting solution for Imagemagick , as the question states i was looking more for perceptualdiff  solution!!!

Comment: @QualityThoughts: You didn't *upvote*, but you *accepted* my answer. These are two different things. Both can be applied separately or combined. You do not need to 'accept' an answer that leaves things open to you! (However, if you look at my answer's update which hints at *'There is no option in perceptualdiff to tweak output image'* -- then I think that your question *'Is there a way I can get...?'* was fully answered!)